# Firefox not working properly in Ubuntu at WSL

Tags: firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

not sure if to post this in this forum or in a Windows one.

I have Ubuntu installed in Windows Subsystem for Linux, WSL. I have ubuntu-desktop installed and working using VcXsrv. Every time I execute:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
sudo service dbus start
sudo service x11-common start
gnome-shell --x11 -r
```

And works fine. The point is that if I open Firefox, the web browser is a white page and not able to load any page, if I write something in the search bar, it disappears when I press enter. I get this on the terminal:

```
[GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI
[GFX1-]: glxtest: process failed (received signal 11)
[Parent 2843, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-HSiFn6/firefox-94.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 2843, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-HSiFn6/firefox-94.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
Exiting due to channel error.

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x23005B,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateEffects) Channel error: cannot send/recv

Exiting due to channel error.
[Parent 2843, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-HSiFn6/firefox-94.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 2843, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-HSiFn6/firefox-94.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 2843, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-HSiFn6/firefox-94.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 2843, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-HSiFn6/firefox-94.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 2843, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-HSiFn6/firefox-94.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
Exiting due to channel error.

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x39008C,name=PContent::Msg_FlushTabState) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x390148,name=PContent::Msg_DiscardBrowsingContext) Channel error: cannot send/recv

Exiting due to channel error.

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x39008C,name=PContent::Msg_FlushTabState) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x390148,name=PContent::Msg_DiscardBrowsingContext) Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

I tried another approach also:

```
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Mozilla\ Firefox/firefox.exe
```

This opens Firefox at Windows, the problem is that if I want to open a .html file, I get *Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.*

Any idea?